# Is a normal TrueCrypt partition indistinguishable from random data? (Does it pass a χ² randomness test?)

Tags: security, encryption, truecrypt

If I encrypt an entire partition with TrueCrypt (a standard volume, **not** a hidden volume), would the partition look statistically indistinguishable from random data?

Or would someone be able to prove (possibly using a chi-square test) that the data is indeed not random?

Answer (score 3):

No, it **can be distinguished from random data**. However, it probably doesn't matter in practice.

---

There's an interesting article [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/04/11/tchunt-search-for-truecrypt-volumes/) that explains some of the typical properties of a TrueCrypt container:

> - The suspect file size modulo 512 must equal zero.
> - The suspect file size is at least 19 KB in size (although in practice this is set to 5 MB).
> - The suspect file contents pass a chi-square distribution test.
> - The suspect file must not contain a common file header.

It talks about the program [TCHunt](http://16s.us/TCHunt/index.php), which was specifically designed for finding TrueCrypt containers. One of the properties *is* that it passes a chi square test. However, the modulo 512 operation [gives more clues](http://coreboarder.blogspot.com/2009/07/random-tidbit-on-non-random-data.html), and obviously, only passing a chi square test doesn't mean it's totally random data:

> Truecrypt volumes, which are essentially files, have certain characteristics that allow programs such as TCHunt to detect them with a high *probability*. The most significant, in mathematical terms, is that their modulo division by 512 is 0.

Comment: I think either I'm misunderstanding something or you are misunderstanding something. :-) How is the file size module 512 being zero a sign of a TrueCrypt **partition**? Aren't all partition sizes mod 512 equal to zero nowadays? Or were you talking about *file containers* instead?

Comment: It will find partitions, embedded files, even TrueCrypt embedded [in whole hard drives](http://16s.us/pics/ID_String.png) — even that is proof alone that it's somehow distinguishable. I'm not sure on the algorithmic details exactly, or why that should work, but the fact that it *does* work is enough for me :) And of course, it *will* find false positives, e.g. other files with pure random data.

Comment: For the benefit of others: At the time that I write this, Trend Micro is blacklisting apparently the entirety of 16 Systems' WWW site, and the `16s.us.` hyperlink in this answer leads to a warning page about malware hosting, fraud, or scams on machines with Trend Micro Internet Security installed and running.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. From the TCHunt FAQ: *"Note: If the encrypted volumes are hidden among /dev/urandom created files via dd, they will not stand out."*

Comment: @tlrobinson Interesting, good to know – but if it wasn't possible to find those volumes, why would TCHunt exist?